# Orthographic camera causes clipping issues

Tags: java, libgdx, clipping, orthographic

Using LibGDX to ease my project making a bit, I've come across an issue that I can't seem to find the source of. Whenever I render a model, it appears fine in a projection view, but as soon as I switch to an orthographic view I get some odd clipping issues.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dosu4.png &] 
[image]

As stated, I am using LibGDX, if you need OpenGL equivalents just ask. Here are some parts of the code, more available upon request:

```
    public Camera(String type) {
    if (type.contains("perspective")) {
        position = new Vector3(1, 2, 1);
        lookAt = new Vector3(0, 1, 0);

        perspectiveCamera = new PerspectiveCamera(67,
                Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
        perspectiveCamera.position.set(position);
        perspectiveCamera.lookAt(lookAt);
        perspectiveCamera.near = 1f;
        perspectiveCamera.far = 300f;
        perspectiveCamera.update();
    }
    if (type.contains("orthographic")) {
        position = new Vector3(1, 1, 1);
        lookAt = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
        orthographicCamera = new OrthographicCamera(
                Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
        orthographicCamera.position.set(position);
        orthographicCamera.lookAt(lookAt);
        orthographicCamera.near = 1f;
        orthographicCamera.far = 300f;
        orthographicCamera.zoom = 0.005f;

        orthographicCamera.update();
    }
}
```

----Change class

```
@Override
public void render() {
    Vector3 translate = new Vector3(isTrue(input.D)
            + (isTrue(input.A) * -1), 0, isTrue(input.W)
            + (isTrue(input.S) * -1)).nor().crs(
            new Vector3(0.05f, 0.05f, 0.05f));
    camera.perspectiveCamera.translate(translate);//Change to orthographic accordingly
    camera.perspectiveCamera.update();//Change to orthographic accordingly

    // Temporary (testing)
    Gdx.gl.glViewport(0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(),
            Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    batch.begin(camera.getPerspectiveCamera());//Change to orthographic accordingly

    for (int n = 0; n < world.entities.size; n++) {
        instance = world.entities.get(n).modelInstance;
        instance.transform.setToTranslation(world.entities.get(n).position);
        world.entities.get(n).modelInstance = instance;
        batch.render(world.entities.get(n).modelInstance, environment);
    }

    batch.end();
}
```

Comment: It seems to me like depth test is disabled.

Comment: Oddly enough it seems depthtest hides it completely. LibGDX is confusing me.

Comment: Why are you trying to use ortho camera for 3d? Usually perspective camera is used for that.

Comment: I have my reasons, and I found the error! Turns out that LibGDX has a native file format that is preferred over .obj / .fbx files. Using a converter seems to have solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by converting files to the native file format for LibGDX